# How to perform time operations (not date operations) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, time

I need a function build a simple function to make time operations, to add or subtract time (not dates). I first tought use JS date operations, something like this (to add 1 year, 1 month and 25 days to 3 months and 3 days. But this has the unconvenient of month numbering (how to represent zero month?) and it doesn't seem to be the more appropriate way to perform these operations.

```
function dataSum (d1, d2) {
        var t2 = d2.getTime();
        var t1 = d1.getTime();
        return parseInt( (t2+t1)/(24*3600*1000) );
    }

dataSum(new Date(1,0,25), new Date(0, 2, 3));    
Logger.log(dataSum( new Date(1,0,25), new Date(0, 2, 3) ));
```

How to perform time operations (not date operations) this way?

Comment: The Date prototype has APIs for manipulating hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript Date objects are convertable to and from unix time stamps.

```
Number(new Date()) => 1393512073675

new Date(1393512073675) => Thu Feb 27 2014 14:41:13 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

In this form you can perform any operation on them, that you could do with a number.